# Toggling a absolute DIV is not working after firsttime

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.pallete').hide();
$(document).delegate('.pick', 'click', function () {
  var pos = $(this).offset();
  var x = pos.left - $(window).scrollLeft() + $(this).width();
  var y = pos.top - $(window).scrollTop() + $(this).height();
  $('.pallete').css({
    top: y + "px",
    left: x + "px",
  }).show();
});

$(document).delegate('.col', 'click', function () {
  var pos = $(this).css('background-color');
  $('.pick').css('background-color', pos);
  $(this).parents('div').fadeOut();
});
```

Here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/zPNk3/5/.
The problem is when I click first time on `.pick` element the '.palette' element is shown properly. But when I click next time the same is not working.

Answer (score 5):

When you do `$(this).parents('div').fadeOut()`, you’re fading out *all* `<div>` parents of the element. You’re only showing `.pallete`.

Try:

```
$(this).closest('.pallete').fadeOut();
```

[It works!](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/zPNk3/6/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I was in a small confusion that closest may also consider sibling elements, I did not use it. But after seeing this answer my doubt is cleared. Thanks again.

Comment: You can do $(this).parents('.pallete').fadeOut(); which will work only on parent elements with pallete class.
Or even:  $(this).parents('.pallete').first().fadeOut();

Comment: @paulina: Except `.closest()` is the most correct, so I‘m using that. It is exactly the same as `$(this).parents('.pallete').first()`, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Look at the row div, that should not be hidden,

```
$(document).delegate('.col', 'click', function () {
  var pos = $(this).css('background-color');
  $('.pick').css('background-color', pos);
  //$(this).parents('div').fadeOut(); // this is wrong
  $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(); // fixed
});
```